# How to use user input with RSpec / Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

How do I use the ruby gets.chomp to run on rspec ?

```
example RUBY::: 
username = gets.chomp
puts "Please type username"
password = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter password"
puts "your username is #{username}"

example RSPEC

feature ' ' do
  scenario 'login', :js => true do
    visit "www.fb.com"
    fill_in 'username', with: "WHAT YOU TYPED"   # how to get/use input here?
    fill_in 'password', with: "WHAT YOU ENTERED"
    click_on "Login"
  do
end
```

my question is how to use the gets.chomp of ruby to run this on rspec properly with this type of commands used?
I want an output of...

$rspec spec/EXAMPLE.rb

Please type username: *_*

Please enter password:**_**

what you entered will be the one used on the commands on logging in on a website.

Comment: `gets` (read from console/stdin) is not available in an automated environment. Instead the username would come from reading the appropriate field in RoR. See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara for a quick example of how to supply values to `fill_in`.

Comment: Yes sir... what I like to do is when I run my ruby file
example... $rspec spec/RUBYEXAMPLE.rb
it will promt username and password first before proceeding on my main program which is loggin in on a specific website... thanks!